# How to add key pairs to object literals using loop--WITHOUT overriding existing entries?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, key, literals

I'm reading input field 'name' and 'value' attributes from ul lists. No two lists have the same amount of inputs and the 'name' and 'value' attributes are unknown till read.

```html
<ul id="options_set1">
    <li><input name="width" value="10" /></li>
    <li><input name="height" value="20" /></li>
    <li><input name="depth" value="5" /></li>
</ul>
<ul id="options_set2">
    <li><input name="finish" value="printed" /></li>
    <li><input name="mounting" value="spacer" /></li>
</ul>
```

I iterate through all the inputs, gathering ul id 'options_set_X' as the literal for my objects, and name:value pairs:

```js
var signState = {}; //My object to be populated

var optionSet = '';
var optionName = '';
var optionValue = '';

$("ul li input").each(function() {
  var optionSet = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
  signState[optionSet] = {};
  optionName = $(this).attr('name');
  optionValue = $(this).val();
  signState[optionSet][optionName] = optionValue;
});
```

What I cannot wrap my head around is how to prevent this loop from replacing any existing name:value pairs in each 'optionSet' literal in the object?

I suspect it is because I restart the signState[optionSet] = {}; literals.

I need a way to add name:value pairs for a given literal without disturbing any existing associations.

Nothing I read online deals with this specific case, because I use variables for both key names and key values - which complicates matters.

Comment: Just wondering.. does checking if the variable is set not work? Just use an if statement like the following: `if(signState[option]) return;` to skip as soon as you see an existing value.

Comment: You are reseting your object in each loop iteration `signState[optionSet] = {};`. Use the that command if `signState[optionSet] == 'undefined'`

Comment: Also just curious, where is optionH3 defined?

Comment: I'm guessing he meant `signState[optionSet][optionName]` by `signState[optionH3][optionName]`

Comment: Yes, the optionH3 should be optionSet - corrected now.

Comment: @somethinghere , I tried something similar to what you are suggesting, but I don't know how to (for lack of a better word) 'push' a key pair to the end of a literal in an object. I've looked into .extend() as well, but it requires that I build multiple objects and merge them. Somehow extend() seems really unsightly to do this. I know there should be a simpler way.

Comment: So what do you want exactly? **All** the name and values **or** just the first set to appear?

Comment: When a variable is defined and you call it, it will return its value. If that value is not 0, you can use this to define it: `myvalue[myKey] = myvalue[myKey] || 'any value';`- if `myvalue[myKey] ` exists, it won't overwrite it, otherwise it will default to the second value. Also, an `object` does not 'extend' or 'push' - it will always appear alphabetical, so you can't append it at the end.

Comment: @JSelser , I want all the name:value pairs to be added to their respective optionSet literal. Basically I'm harvesting all options as in the production code I will have no idea how many name:value pairs will exist per option set.

Comment: @somethinghere your suggestion to first check if the literal exists with an if statement worked perfectly! Can't believe I missed this - time to check who put decaf in the coffee machine! Thanks a million!

Comment: @Matthew6 I also put it into an answer (before you told me it worked) because I think the comment was getting a bit long :) Enjoy caffeine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var signState = {};

$("ul li input").each(function() {
    var set, name, value;
    set    = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
    name   = $(this).attr('name');
    value  = $(this).val();

    /* Create a fresh object if it doesn't exist, 
     * otherwise assign it the existing one. */
    signState[set] = signState[set] || {};

    /* Again, assign a fresh value if it was undefined or empty 
     * otherwise assign it the existing one. */
    signState[set][name] = signState[set][name] || value;

});
```

Now if the value you are setting is `false` or `0`, then it will be overwritten. If you don't want that, you have to use the tertiary operator to ensure you get it right:

```
signState[set][name] = typeof signState[set][name] !== "undefined"
    ? signState[set][name]
    : value;
```

The tertiary operator syntax is as follows: `definition = when is true ? this : else this;` - which can be very useful for this.

Answer (score 0):

Following from somethinghere's comment and answer, I was able to get perfect results with this:

```js
var signState = {}; //My object to be populated

var optionSet = '';
var optionName = '';
var optionValue = '';

$("ul li input").each(function() {
  optionSet = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
  signState[optionSet] = {};
  
  //The solution - because it prevents overriding existing literals, so name:value pairs are neatly written to each literal if they don't already exist
  if(!signState[optionSet]) { 
    signState[optionSet] = {};
  }
  //---------
  
  optionName = $(this).attr('name');
  optionValue = $(this).val();
  signState[optionSet][optionName] = optionValue;
});
```

Comment: Looks like it'll work, but you dont need to declare the variables globally. (This only increases the room for error, and uses global memory for something local). And i really wouldnt use the word option so often as it just looks repetitive, but it works!